# Drop Down Panel in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, window, expander, collapsable

I'm trying to create a drop down menu like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gWiBj.png) in .Net.
 I can't think of the name of it so I'm not sure what control to search for, any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: collapsible panel http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/TgXPPanel.aspx

P.S: If u like da answer, dont forget 2 accept it. Thanks

Comment: retag your question. Seriously. No `drop`, no `down`, no `arrow`. `WinForms` or `WPF` or `ASP.Net` or `YetAnotherMSTechnology`

Comment: Hey I've retagged it. The problem was I didn't know the name to start with so I didn't know what tag to use- kind of chicken and egg. Also collapsible is spelt wrongly in the tagging system..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find in google for collapsible window in .net you will get many sample application. Any way [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/static/Collapsible__Panel.aspx) is a link may help you to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an [Expander](http://www.wpftutorial.net/Expander.html) with ListView in terms of WPF.

Comment: Expander! Thats the word, thanks. Found a WinForms control that I'll use http://jfblier.wordpress.com/2011/02/16/window-form-expander/